# Problem with adding a Border to the Header and Body of a material-table

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I'm using [material-table](https://material-table.com/#/) in my React App. I want to add left and right border to the table.

Here is the code for [overriding](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/component-overriding) Header and Body components.

```
      components={{
        Header: props => (
          <Box ml={2} mr={2}>
            <MTableHeader  {...props}/>
          </Box>
        ),
        Body: props => (
          <Box ml={2} mr={2}>
            <MTableBody  {...props}/>
          </Box>
        ),
      }}
```

When I try to add the borders, table header and body is distorted like this:

[image]

I also tried overriding the Table component with Paper but it looks like Paper is a wrapper to the actual table.